# Корректная форма прощания с педагогом

Tags: грамотная-речь

Корректно ли прощаться с педагогом словом "Счастливо"?

Как назвать расставание на время? Разлукой, прощанием?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, это излишне фамильярно - так прощаются с приятелями или младшими по возрасту людьми, к которым относятся благожелательно. Для прощания с преподавателем подходит нейтральное "до свидания!"; можно добавить имя и отчество. Расставание обозначают отдельным словом только при прощании с близкими людьми ("разлука" - обычно при длительном расставании с *возлюбленым/-ой*). В случае преподавателя можно сказать, например, "попрощались до следующего занятия".